# Uneven CSS Column Grids

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

[image]

From my research in this problem, I've learned CSS grids appear to capable of quite complex behaviour. My scenario is simpler and I was expecting to have 4 evenly spaced panel boxes with code below. My question is why the horizontal gap is not centred in the middle vertically? I worked through trail&error to test various combinations of alignment, justification and grid specs but could not find a solution. What do I need to add to my code to have the gap centred vertically on the page?

```css
.main-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: stretch;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.container {
    border: 3px solid black;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.shared {
    justify-content: center;
    border: none;
}

.sub-container {
    border: 3px solid black;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="container" id="A">
        <h1>Section A</h1>
        <p id="A-values">A Values</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="B">
        <h1>Section B</h1>
        <p id="B-values">B Values</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="C">
        <h1>Section C</h1>
        <p id="C-values">C Values</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container shared" id="D">
        <div class="sub-container">
            <h2>SubSection D1</h2>
            <p id="D1-values">D1 Values</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-container">
            <h2>SubSection D2</h2>
            <p id="D2-values">D2 Values</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-container">
            <h2>SubSection D3</h2>
            <p id="D3-values">D3 Values</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the height is set to match the longest item on a row, the height on the bottom row is different to the top simply because there's more content in one of it's columns.

Try setting the rows as you have the columns, add `grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);` to the `main-container` class